# Removing Spaces before and after custom commands

Tags: latex, command, space

I have a problem using Latex and custom commands. The custom command \refChap adds spaces before and after the inserted text every time when used. I would like a solution that suppresses said spaces.

The following example should explain my problem in depth:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,
            left=2cm,
            right=2cm,
            top=2cm,
            bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{6 pt} % paragraph 6 pt
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % no indent at paragraph start

\usepackage{nameref}



\newcommand\Section[1]{ %
    \section{#1}
    \label{#1}
}

\newcommand\refChap[1]{
Chapter \ref{#1} (\nameref{#1} on p.\pageref{#1})
}

\begin{document}
When I reference \refChap{Header}, I'd expect there to be exactly one space before and none after the inserted text. However, the command will add one space each before and after the command, resulting in two spaces being before the word \"{}Chapter\"{} and one before the comma.

This behavior can be better seen when I do not add any spaces before and after\refChap{Header}, as I would expect there to be no space in the final result as well. However, there are.

\Section{Header}

I would like to have a solution to surpress those additional spaces, so that 

\textit{When I reference \textbackslash{}refChap\{Header\}, I'd expect [...]}

would look like:

\textit{When I reference Chapter 1 (Header on p.1), I'd expect [...]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Anyone any suggestions?

Comment: Consider asking on the "TeX - LaTeX" subsite of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The additional spaces are caused by the unprotected line endings, which will act like a space. To avoid this, place a `%` at the end of lines:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,
            left=2cm,
            right=2cm,
            top=2cm,
            bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{6 pt} % paragraph 6 pt
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % no indent at paragraph start

\usepackage{nameref}



\newcommand\Section[1]{%
    \section{#1}%
    \label{#1}%
}

\newcommand\refChap[1]{%
Chapter \ref{#1} (\nameref{#1} on p.\pageref{#1})%
}

\begin{document}
When I reference \refChap{Header}, I'd expect there to be exactly one space before and none after the inserted text. However, the command will add one space each before and after the command, resulting in two spaces being before the word \"{}Chapter\"{} and one before the comma.

This behavior can be better seen when I do not add any spaces before and after\refChap{Header}, as I would expect there to be no space in the final result as well. However, there are.

\Section{Header}

I would like to have a solution to surpress those additional spaces, so that 

\textit{When I reference \textbackslash{}refChap\{Header\}, I'd expect [...]}

would look like:

\textit{When I reference Chapter 1 (Header on p.1), I'd expect [...]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't think the answer was so easy  :)